# I need completed reference of caml query

Tags: sharepoint-2010, caml

I am using sharepoint 2010 and looking for  Collaborative Application Markup Language (CAML) struct.

I searched for it on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms467521.aspx, but it seems to be not a caml completed reference since there are no properties explaination.

Where can I find a complete reference for it or xsd?

Comment: I believe the reference is complete. Why do you think it's not complete? That said, the schema is located here on a default setup : `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\XML\CamlQuery.xsd`. I'm note however, that the schema is accurate regarding the possibilities offered by the query engine.

Comment: I don't see property LookupId on the site. So i think that.

Answer (score 0):

Try `CamlQuery.xsd` from `java-sharepoint-library` on Google Code.

https://code.google.com/p/java-sharepoint-library/source/browse/trunk/xsd/CamlQuery.xsd?r=35